# More pythonic way to create list of dicts from dict where list elements are dict of form `{v:[k1, k2, k3]}`

Tags: python

I need to create a list of dictionaries from a dict.  The original dict will have to will have keys have do not repeat but values can.  For example:

```
{ 'b': 68, 'c': 68, 'x': 68, 'z': 401, 'aa':401, 'a': 2}
```

I need to create a list of dicts from the above that would look like this:

```
[{68: ['b', 'c', 'x']}, {401: ['z', 'aa']}, {2: ['a']}]
```

What have I tried? I have tried this and it works but I am certain there is probably are better way to accomplish the same result.

```
lofd=[]
origdict = { 'b': 68, 'c': 68, 'x': 68, 'z': 401, 'aa':401, 'a': 2}
for i in origdict.items():
    k = i[0]
    v = i[1]
    try:
        d[v].append(k)
    except:
        d = {v:[]}
        d[v].append(k)
    if d not in lofd:
        lofd.append(d)

lofd
[{68: ['b', 'c', 'x']}, {401: ['z', 'aa']}, {2: ['a']}]
```

I have seen other questions that one might consider duplicate to this question, but the answers to those questions do not cover how to convert a dictionary to a list of dictionaries.  There are plenty of answer that should how to invert a dictionary which is kinda like what I am trying to do, but I am not inverting the dictionary.  There are answers that show create a tuple of tuples from a dict, but I do need a list of dictionaries, not immutable tuples.

Comment: oops thanks that's a typo. I will update the question.

Comment: Are all the values (new keys) guaranteed to be hashable?

Comment: @pault yes ... at least I think so.

Comment: This is very convoluted code... Can you fix all the typos and bad variable names first so the question is useful to others?

Comment: Thanks @TomKarzes. I removed the typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using a list comprehension as well:

```
[dict((_, )) for _ in {v: [_k for _k, _v in d.items() if _v ==  v] for v in d.values()}.items()]
```

To show it works

```
>>> d = { 'b': 68, 'c': 68, 'x': 68, 'z': 401, 'aa':401, 'a': 2}
>>> [dict((_, )) for _ in {v: [_k for _k, _v in d.items() if _v ==  v] for v in d.values()}.items()]
[{68: ['b', 'c', 'x']}, {401: ['z', 'aa']}, {2: ['a']}]
```

**Note** I don't particularly know what usage this is for but If you could I'd suggest using a dict instead of a list of dicts as this comprehension is slower than just the dict comprehension alone. If possible I'd suggest using just the dict comprehension which would be much better in my opinion although returns a dict instead of a list of dicts which is **more pythonic** or at least makes more sense especially since you can iterate over it the same with `dict.items()`.

```
{v: [_k for _k, _v in d.items() if _v ==  v] for v in d.values()}
```

This returns a dict as follows:

```
{68: ['b', 'c', 'x'], 401: ['z', 'aa'], 2: ['a']}
```

Comment: I didn't particular care about order but others may need to preserve order.

Comment: Please see my note, as that approach is the most performant and IMO pythonic as a list of dicts to me should be a dict in this case as each dict has one key and each key is unique.

Comment: I also reworked the original comprehension as the new way doesn't need any other libraries and is better/faster

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest the following. Untested.

```
from collections import defaultdict

a  = { 'b': 66, 'b': 68, 'c': 68, 'x': 68, 'z': 401, 'aa':401, 'a': 2}

t = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in a.items():
    t[v].append(k)

o = [dict((p,)) for p in t.items()]
```

Answer (score 1):

Figure out if the list contains the wanted key, and if it does, append the value to the list. Otherwise, append a new dictionary:

```
a = { 'b': 66, 'b': 68, 'c': 68, 'x': 68, 'z': 401, 'aa':401, 'a': 2 }
b = []

for key, val in a.items():
    if (any(val in d for d in b)):
        b[next(i for i, d in enumerate(b) if val in d)][val].append(key)
    else:
        d = {}
        d[val] = [key]
        b.append(d)

print(b)
```

Output:

```
[{68: ['b', 'c', 'x']}, {401: ['z', 'aa']}, {2: ['a']}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like that.

```py
a = { 'b': 68, 'c': 68, 'x': 68, 'z': 401, 'aa':401, 'a': 2}
b = {}

for k, v in a.items():
    b.setdefault(v, []).append(k)

c = [{k: b[k]} for k in b]
print(c)
```

Output:

```py
[{68: ['b', 'c', 'x']}, {401: ['z', 'aa']}, {2: ['a']}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat same but a bit optimized:

```
a  = { 'b': 66, 'b': 68, 'c': 68, 'x': 68, 'z': 401, 'aa':401, 'a': 2}
b  = {}
for k,v in a.items():
    val = b.get(v,[])
    val.append(k)
    b[v] = val

lst = []
for k,v in b.items():
    d = dict()
    d[k] = v
    lst.append(d)

print(lst)
```

Output:

```
[{68: ['b', 'c', 'x']}, {401: ['z', 'aa']}, {2: ['a']}]
```

Comment: That's close but not quite a list of dicts like: `[{68: ['b', 'c', 'x']}, {401: ['z', 'aa']}, {2: ['a']}]`.

Answer (score 0):

[Enumerate()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) method adds a counter to an iterable and returns it in a form of enumerate object.

```
origdict = { 'b': 66, 'b': 68, 'c': 68, 'x': 68, 'z': 401, 'aa':401, 'a': 2}
my_list = []
my_dict = {}

for index, (key, value) in enumerate(origdict.items()):
    if value in my_dict:
        my_dict[value].append(key)
    else:
        #validate is not first index of list
        if index > 0:
            my_list.append(my_dict)
        my_dict = {}
        my_dict[value] = [key]

    #validate last index of list
    if index == len(origdict)-1:
        my_list.append(my_dict)

print(my_list)
```

O/P:

```
[{68: ['b', 'c', 'x']}, {401: ['z', 'aa']}, {2: ['a']}]
```

Answer (score 0):

use `defuhaltdict` in this case

```
from collections import defaultdict
dic = defaultdict(list)
k= { 'b': 66, 'b': 68, 'c': 68, 'x': 68, 'z': 401, 'aa':401, 'a': 2}
for ke, v in k.items():
     dic[v]+=[ke]

print(dict(dic))
```

output

```
{68: ['b', 'c', 'x'], 401: ['z', 'aa'], 2: ['a']}
```